# Intellij Idea creates eclipse files and folders

Tags: eclipse, intellij-idea

I'm using InteliJ Idea Ultimate 2019.2 and I seem to have some misconfigurations that I cannot figure out. And I cannot find anything in the documentation. While scanning and indexing idea is auto creating some eclipse specific folders and files that I don't want to have in my enviroment. The ide creates .settings folder with eclipse prefs files, the .classpath file, the .factorypath for annotation processing and a .project file.

It seems that the maven project itself could be the key. But there are no updates on the plugins.

I want to get rid of that stuff and I simply cannot figure out what should have been done earlier.

Comment: See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/import-project-from-eclipse-page-1.html#Import_Project_from_Eclipse._Page_1.xml . Make sure you didn't configure IDE to store module settings in Eclipse format.

Answer (score 3):

Since I couldn't find any configuration issues, I stopped every program on the computer one at a time. My MS Visual Code was the problem. I use it for text editing. It uses a maven plugin which is connected to eclipse. I deactivated the plugin and now the folders and file will not appear again. I should switch back to Sublime or Notepad++. Sorry about this question but this strange bahaivour was driving me nuts for two day.